# Multibit Won't Open

Tags: multibit

I have NOT done any kind of system restore (don't have the hard drive space for that)

The multibit application won't open. I tried installing the latest version, didn't seem to do anything.

I've updated Java and rebooted. Didn't help.

It's been many months since I've even looked at my BTC. I can't even remember what a wallet is supposed to look like... Can someone confirm it should be called saving.wallet? That's my impression from their site but a search of my PC shows no such file?

Comment: What operating system are you using? What error message do get when you [run it from the command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5774970/run-jar-file-in-command-prompt)?

Comment: Your OS is need to answer this question as Multibit will create a default wallet in different places depending on the OS. If that wallet is "screwed" it may cause issues opening.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Trouble shooting page](https://multibit.org/en/help/v0.5/help_troubleshooting.html)